# MySQL create table command occur ERROR 1064 (42000)

Tags: mysql

An error occurred while executing a SQL through the command line. What is the problem? Syntax looks like it's not wrong. What shall I do?

```
[root@SHB-L0035222 bin]# mysql -u dubbom -D dubbomonitor -p -t </tmp/create.sql
Enter password:
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 3: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USING BTREE,
  KEY `index_method` (`method`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index_invoke_da' at line 17

[root@SHB-L0035222 bin]# cat /tmp/create.sql
use dubbomonitor;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `dubbo_invoke`;
CREATE TABLE `dubbo_invoke` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `invoke_date` date NOT NULL,
  `service` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `method` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `consumer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `provider` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `invoke_time` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `success` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `failure` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `elapsed` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `concurrent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `max_elapsed` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `max_concurrent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_service` (`service`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index_method` (`method`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index_invoke_date` (`invoke_date`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index_invoke_time` (`invoke_time`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

Comment: What version of mysql are you using?

Comment: My colleague installed MySQL 5.1, I know what the problem is, thank you.

Comment: @Tan What was the problem? You can post it as answer

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL version is too old, some of the high version of the syntax is not supported.

Thanks you, @Wes Doyle